# Cannot open a form in the same project VB Net Visual Studio 2022

Tags: vb.net

I cannot use `[Form Name].show()` method. From my understanding, it's not 'public' or something. I cannot find any other possible fixes for this on the internet.

The error code is BC30469

[image]

Comment: First you need to get an instance of it `new Form2().Show`

Comment: make the class `Form2` public by `public shared class Form2`

Comment: That indicates that `Form2` has no default instance. As far as I can tell, that is unaffected by whether the class is public or not. The usual reason for a form class to not have a default instance is that it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. Have you added a constructor to `Form2` that has parameters and not added one that doesn't?

Comment: To understand what default instances are and how they work, you might like to read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html).

Comment: @MuhammadZakaria, there's no such thing as a `Shared` class in VB. The VB equivalent of a C# `static` class is a module. They behave a bit differently while writing code but they compile to the same thing.

Comment: For future reference, DO NOT post only a picture of your code or error message. ALWAYS post each as text, formatted appropriately. If you think including a screenshot as well adds value then by all means do so, but that should not be all you include.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, that would not compile as is, because you cannot start a line of code with `New`. You'd either have to introduce a variable or else use `Call New Form2().Show()`. This is the one case I've found where `Call` is actually useful. That said, it might be more appropriate to address the reason that there's no default instance in the first place. This may be an XY problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney good point John, I haven't been using VB.Net in a ages, its perfectly valid in C#.